# Can PHP be made aware of Apache alias?

Tags: php, apache, alias

Using a webserver with an Alias in the httpd.conf file, e.g.

```
    Alias /Videos /Users/myuser/Movies
```

works flawlessly, i.e. http://[server]/Videos points to my personal Movies folder.

But in writing a PHP script I have to make the script 'aware' of this alias,  AFAIK PHP is not aware of Alias (and other settings) of Apache.
Is there a way to get this alias setting into PHP ?

I am running Apache 2.4.x and PHP 7.x on Ubuntu, Android and macOS.

Comment: That is against the idea of an Alias. So the short answer is "no". Why don't you ask you _real_ question, so tell us what and why you need to do instead of stating that you "have to"?

Comment: Actually the above is only true in a precise technical manner. You cannot "make php aware" of the Alias. However PHP is provided with the original requested URL, so the requested pathn which is what you are interested in I assume. Take a look into the `$_REQUEST` super global array.